# Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[rel= {myString} ]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a small application and i got stuccked on some small error.

firebug:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[rel=!a1=0,1000,0,0,0,1,0,0.4]     jquery.1.11.js (line 1471)
throw new Error( "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg );
```

What the app does:

[not important] it sends some form data to some php for processinf and retrieves and display received data.

After data is displayed it adds to link some variables to store data [ in case the user needs to send the page with queries to some other user]

At page load the process is repeated [script sends data; php process data; send back etc]. The problem is that I get this error in firebug. Any idea?

This is some of the code:

After form submit and data is received:

```
function addTolink(){
    /* I will set the vars manually they are not important */
    var tip = 0;
    var suma = 1000;
    var pai = 0;
    var cdm = 0;
    var bdm = 0;
    var fdb = 1;
    var sni = 0;
    var mbp = 0;

    var qlink = tip+','+suma+','+pai+','+cdm+','+bdm+','+fdb+','+sni+','+mbp ;
        window.location = tpl2[0]+'#!'+'a1='+qlink; /* adds #!a1=0,1200,0,0,0,0,0,0 */
}
```

After page has completely loaded [ $(document).ready( //]:

```
var permalink = window.location.toString().split('#!');
            if(permalink[1]){
            var nrVars = permalink[1].split('&');
            var data = [];

                for(var i= '0'; i < nrVars.length ; i++ ){
                    var qq = nrVars[i].split('=');
                    var vfOrm = qq[1].split(',');
                        /* 
                        ** working here with fvOrm //
                        ** like setting tip_date and pia and all other vars used below
                        */

                    var f = ['cs.'+tip_date+'&suma='+vfOrm[1]+'&persIntretinere='+pia+'&condMunca='+cod_munca+'&bonuriDeMasa='+vfOrm[4]+'&functieDeBaza='+fdb+'&salFixNeimpozabil='+imp+'&contrAMBP='+vfOrm[7]];
                    data.push(f);
                }
                runlink( data ); // function that makes the query and displays data again on a page freshly loaded.
            }
```

Comment: if you need any other details i will be happy to answer any questions.

Comment: WTH is that selector supposed to mean? If you think of `!a1=0,1000,0,0,0,1,0,0.4` as a string in the `rel` attribute, then you should wrap it in quotes.

Comment: @Bergi actually the browser threaded the part of the address after # as [rel=!a1=0,1000,0,0,0,1,0,0.4] selector witch is invalid expression in jq.1.10. the actual address was: mysqite.com/somepage/#!a1=0,1000,0,0,0,1,0,0.4&a2=0,1200,0,0,0,1,0,0.4

Answer (score 0):

just in case someone gets this problem: downgrade jquery to 1.7. this worked for me. if that doesen`t work, try another ... this is a real odd thing.